# PHP Laravel : How to get client browser/ Device?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a laravel application where I want to keep track of client browser details such as browser name.
How do I do it using Laravel ?

```
public function postUser(Request $request)
    {        
            $user = new User();                                 
            $user->name = $request->Input(['name']);           
            $device=   $request->header('User-Agent');
            dd($device);
            $user->save();            
            return redirect('userSavePage');          
    }
```

I have used this  `$device=   $request->header('User-Agent');` 
But while I dd() the output I get something Like this:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
```

How do I get actual browser details?

Comment: Use a regex to get the browser and browser version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First add the package to your composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "hisorange/browser-detect": "2.*" // For laravel 5.* versions
        "hisorange/browser-detect": "1.*" // For laravel 4.* versions
    }
}
```

After the composer update/install add the service provider to your app.php:

```
'providers' => array(
    // ...
    'hisorange\BrowserDetect\Provider\BrowserDetectService',
    // ...
)
```

Add the alias to the aliases in your app.php:

```
'aliases' => array(
    // ...
    'BrowserDetect' => 'hisorange\BrowserDetect\Facade\Parser',
)
```

You must use personal configurations, just publish the package's configuration files, (plugins.php also published with this)

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

You can get result informations by simply call on the facade.

```
// You can always get the result object from the facade if you wish to operate with it.
BrowserDetect::detect(); // Will resolve and return with the 'browser.result' container.

// Calls are mirrored to the result object for easier use.
BrowserDetect::browserVersion(); // return '3.6' string.

// Supporting human readable formats.
BrowserDetect::browserName(); // return 'Firefox 3.6' string.

// Or can be objective.
BrowserDetect::browserFamily(); // return 'Firefox' string.
```

For details: https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect

Comment: it return "HiSoRange Generic OS" on osFamily.

Comment: @JavidAliyev hi i checked the package its great but i want to ask how to get browser unique fingureprint or signature, is that even possible,?Because i was wondering push notification such as one signal get track of some signature so is there anyway of doing so ?

Comment: Please, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085230/ways-to-create-a-unique-user-fingerprint-in-php

Answer (score 38):

I ended using the faster, and simpler way:

```
$request->header('User-Agent');
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: It do not detect exactly which browser .

Comment: @CongLB Yep, it only gets the User-Agent which is de identifier of the browser's technologies and details. Yo can check Panjesh answer to understand the User-Agent.

Answer (score 8):

For most of newest laravel versions, this method is working :

```php
Route::get('/agent', function () {
    return request()->userAgent();
});
```

Comment: it returns all the user agent NOT the specific one you're using

Answer (score 3):

Use [Agent](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-detector-mobile-browser-name-version-platform-device-robot-crawler-user-language-8499bee7607c)

which let you detect user browser and platform and also browser's/platform's version

https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-detector-mobile-browser-name-version-platform-device-robot-crawler-user-language-8499bee7607c

In the new version you can also detect the robots.

Answer (score 3):

With latest version of **BrowserDetect** package, you can get browser information as below:

Install using below command:

> composer require hisorange/browser-detect

Once installed, add dependency in **config/app.php** file.

Add below line in providers array.

> hisorange\BrowserDetect\ServiceProvider::class,

Add below line in alias array.

> 'BrowserDetect' => hisorange\BrowserDetect\Facade::class,

Include package in any class file as below to use:

> use BrowserDetect;

After this you can access **BrowserDetect** methods as explained in below package link:

[BrowserDetect package link](https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the explanations from [here](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-detector-mobile-browser-name-version-platform-device-robot-crawler-user-language-8499bee7607c), in order to detect the Rest API consumers like Postman and Insomnia, i merged with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992800/9808260) answer and ended up having the following source code that performed better in my scenario

```
Route::get('browser', function () {

//create new agent instance
$agent = new Jenssegers\Agent\Agent();

//check if agent is robot
if ($agent->isRobot()) {
    return $agent->robot();
}
//if agent is not robot then get agent browser and platform like Chrome in Linux
$agent = $agent->browser() . " in " . $agent->platform();
//if agent browser and platform not obtained, then we check the agent technology
if ($agent == ' in ') {
    $agent =  request()->header('User-Agent');
}
return $agent;});
```

So from the code above, i can detect browser, platform, robot and rest consumers like Postman and Insomnia.