# How to get exact browser name and version in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have used this `$device=$request->header('User-Agent')`; But while I `dd()` the output I get something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

How do I get actual browser details?

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294031/6063268
I think it'll help

Answer (score 1):

You may use PHP's get_browser() function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php
In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on your system.

```
get_browser( $request->header('User-Agent') , true);
// Returns an Array with various browser information
```