# How to add visitor history in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to create a function when the user login will send data browser and ip to the
 database  in laravel 5.4?

Comment: Have you created a table and its related model to persist the data? Also, have you done any research on the available composer packages or other answers on stack overflow? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293444/php-laravel-how-to-get-client-browser-device/37294031#37294031) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268683/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-laravel-5-1)?

Comment: @kidA I've seen it, but before I didn't know how to put it on the controller login. but now it has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LoginController in;

```
  protected function authenticated(Request $request,$user)
 {
     //Do something
 }
```

Comment: i must set in routes for this function?

Comment: No! This function is triggered when the user login.